# How to share something on facebook from my iOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook, share

I'm adding share functionalities to my iOS app (I have to support down to iOS 4.3). In the Facebook case, the behavior I want to implement is:

if the facebook app is present on the iDevice
then open it and go to share view with everything already pre-filled

else
open www.facebook.com/sharer.php?[etc] in safari (or whatever browser) to share my page.

I wrote this :

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@", facebookShareLink]];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

    } else {

        NSString *facebookLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@", facebookShareLink, titleToShare];
        facebookLink = [facebookLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookLink]];
    }
```

When the Facebook app is NOT installed it works pretty well but when it's installed then it opens but it won't go to the share view.

I read somewhere that the URL schemes are not supported anymore (I don't have the source). Is that true?

Then is there still a way to do this without integrating the Facebook iOS SDK? I don't want to add this SDK, I just need the sharing functionality not all the Graph stuff.

EDIT:
I don't want my app to share itself sth on a social media but to prompt the user and give him the ability to do it himself easily. I think I shouldn't have to authenticate with a Facebook app or a Twitter app in order to do that, should I? The user will authenticate himself in the app or on the mobile website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally made a solution using the iOS built-in facebook share dialog (SLComposeViewController) that falls back on the website if the user is not using iOS 6

```
NSString *facebookShareLink = @"some link to share";
NSString *titleToShare = @"some title";

// if we're not on iOS 6, SLComposeViewController won't be available. Then fallback on website.
Class composeViewControllerClass = [SLComposeViewController class];

if(composeViewControllerClass == nil || ![composeViewControllerClass isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

    NSString *facebookLink = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@", facebookShareLink, titleToShare];
    facebookLink = [facebookLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookLink]];

} else {

    SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [composeViewControllerClass composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [composeViewController setInitialText:titleToShare];
    [composeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookShareLink]];

    [parentController presentModalViewController:composeViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to just post through http:// link just the way you did http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=%@&t=%@.. what is the link for Posting on FB?

Comment: Am I right that in this case I don't have to register new app on developer.facebook and there is no need in facebook keys and secret?

Comment: Yes indeed. You don't even need the facebook sdk.

Comment: iTunes URL shared in this way is unclickable.

Answer (score 1):

you can use third party components such as ShareKit.
http://getsharekit.com/

Comment: ShareKit requires me to add a Facebook key and secret, just like the Facebook iOS SDK.

Answer (score 1):

you can share in facebook, twitter or by email using uiactivity

```
UIImage *image1 = shareimgview.image;
NSString *str1=[@"Brand: " stringByAppendingString:brand_field.text];
NSString *str2=[@"Product: " stringByAppendingString:product_field.text];
NSString *str3=[@"Model: "stringByAppendingString:model_field.text];
NSString *str4=[@"Comment: "stringByAppendingString:status_field.text];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[str1,myurl,str2,str3,str4, image1];
UIActivityViewController *actviewcon = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:actviewcon animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you looking for a Swift 3 solution, here it is:

```
if let composeVC = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType:serviceType) {
    composeVC.add(object.image())
    composeVC.add(object.url())
    composeVC.setInitialText(object.text())
    presentingVC.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```